# Ember: access a parent view from a route

Tags: view, ember.js, ember-router

Is there a way to access views from an ember route?

My use case: I want to do something similar to jquery accordion (collapsible / expandable) where each accordion item is a different view -- the other views should still be visible, just collapsed (I want to have the expanded accordion view state represented bookmarkable by URL which is why I'm doing it through the router). I was hoping to have subroutes for each accordion item, and for each route override `renderTemplate` to call `accordionItemView.expand()` instead of rendering a template.

How can I access the view from the route? Is this the right way to go about things?

I know I can always set some global variable on the view's insertion or do something with jQuery to look up the view, but I'm wondering if there's a non-hacky way to do this.

Comment: I have solved that using a computed property on the `applicationController`, but it would be nice to know if there's an Ember-way...